# Redis hash or key replace

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, hash, redis

If I had stored an object hash in redis, say this hash:

```
 { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4, e: 5 }
```

And if I knew that my hash value `d` has changed to `10`, can I go about updating that redis hash key value only, rather then fetching the hash, modifying it and writing it back to redis?

I have an object state that I am caching in the redis, and basically once the state changes, I am looking for efficient way to refresh the cache.

Is there a better way to do this?

**Hello I've tried this** :

```
a = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4, e: 5 }
REDIS.mapped_hmset('key', a)
```

So this works :

```
b = REDIS.hgetall('key')
b['d'] = 10
REDIS.mapped_hmset('key', b)
```

But I am looking something if possible to modify the key in redis, or alternative approach.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's important to show what you tried, and explain why it didn't work.

Comment: @theTinMan thanks, I did added what I've tried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking to change (or add) a single value in a hash, you can use the `HSET` command. This does not "fetch" the hash from redis (returning it to you), it only modifies it.

In your case, the command would be `HSET YourHashName d 10`.

[HSET Documentation on redis.io](https://redis.io/commands/hset)

If you find you're changing multiple values at once, then use `HMSET`. This command is more efficient than multiple `HSET` calls to do the same thing, as it is less chatty over the network.

[HMSET Documentation on redis.io](https://redis.io/commands/hmset)

Keep in mind that when adding or changing data within a hash, you don't need to read/get the hash (or any individual hash key values) first. Also, if the hash doesn't exist when setting its data, the hash will be created instead of returning an error.

Comment: @Remember_me I added more info to the answer after seeing your edit now that I know how your code is functioning.